# How to pass $node->nid into update statement

Tags: sql, drupal-7

I am trying to update a node in Drupal 7 using the following code.

```php
db_update('table')
  ->fields(array('column1' => 1))
  ->condition('entity_id', 2, '=')
  ->execute();
```

The statement works as expected: The value of column1 gets updates to 1 where the entity_id = 2.

However, I am trying to replace 2 with the current node.

If I use `return $node->nid;` then the current node gets returned as expected. If I try to put `$node->nid` into the query it doesn't validate.

The following code doesn't return anything; the query just fails.

```
db_update('table')
  ->fields(array('column1' => 1))
  ->condition('entity_id', $node->nid, '=')
  ->execute();
```

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. Would you paste in the error message?

Comment: May you show the complete code you are using? Which hook are you using, and which error code you get, if you get any error code?

Answer (score 0):

Total stab in the dark here:

try

```
global $node;
```

Before the above lines.

Or just assign a variable to  Return %node->nid

and put the variable inside where you have $node->nid?

Comment: Drupal doesn't have any global `$node`.

Comment: @kiamlaluno global $node by itself doesn't do anything...But it should make the $node object visible to the scope of the above function with a single arrow operator in subsequent lines. A shot in the dark in any case.

Comment: If I add `global $node;` in a Drupal function, I would get an error when accessing `$node->nid` because `$node` is not an object (Drupal doesn't initialize `$node`). If the function already gets `$node` as parameter, PHP would probably return an error about overriding a local variable with a global one. The OP should say where it is using that code, as the context is very important, and that information is missing from the question, so far.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Gotcha! Been a while since I've worked with Drupal.... was hoping for a simple one-liner... My how D7 has changed :)

Comment: Wait to see Drupal 8, and you will wonder if that still is Drupal code. `;)`